# i'm facing issue when i run my application in xcode "Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-form

[Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry6V2.jpg)

Comment: Same here... did you find a solution to this?